# Power BI slicer to filter table based on choice of which column to use

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have 2 tables in Power BI of the following structure:

Table A:

| ID | SecondID | Values

| 1   | 20230417  |

| 2   | 20230418   |

| 3   | 20230419   |

...

Table B:

| SecondID | Scenario1 | Scenario2 | Scenario 3|

| 20230417  | TRUE   | TRUE | FALSE |

| 20230418  | TRUE   | FALSE | TRUE |

| 20230419  | FALSE   | FALSE | TRUE |

...

I want to put a slicer on my report that lets the user choose Scenario 1, 2 or 3 & that for then to filter Table A based on the True/False value for the SecondID in that scenario.

i.e. in the above, if the user chose Scenario 1 on the slicer then Table A just becomes row 1 & 2, in Scenario 2 then table A is just row 1 and in Scenario 3 table A is row 2 & 3.

I tried using a Field parameter and the slicer looked as I wanted, but couldn't do the filtering on the other table based on that? Is this possible?

Thanks,